# Omitting a Subtotal that Equals the Subtotal Above It (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a report that has subtotals for each category. I need the subtotals for the three levels that exist to be on but a lot of the time, a subtotal will equal the subtotal above it making it look clumsy and redundant.

Here I have a snippet of what it looks like:

[image]

Category 1 is "Fixed Charges", category 2 is "Fixed Production Costs" and Category 3 is blank in this case.

What I need is something like this:

> IF category 3 subtotal = category 2 subtotal  THEN category 3 subtotal = blank()

[image]

Comment: what's the current code for this measure? simple SUM over a column? or something more complex?

Comment: sorry for delay; basically a simple sum. there is a clause in there to redistribute some account values to a different cost center but it shouldn't affect any solution

Comment: `code` Currency = 
VAR EQ = SUM( Financials[Alloc] )
RETURN

SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    AND( 
        MAX(Financials[ACCOUNT]) = 8010 || MAX(Financials[ACCOUNT]) = 8020 || MAX(Financials[ACCOUNT]) = 8100 || MAX(Financials[ACCOUNT]) = 8110 || MAX(Financials[ACCOUNT]) = 9001,
        IF( ISFILTERED( Financials[COST CENTER] ), .0000000001, blank() )
    ), BLANK(),
    EQ * -1
) `code`